# Use an array stored colour (string) to set UIColor of a label element

Tags: swift, uicolor

I am working on an iOS app (just a personal project at the moment) and I am trying to change a label bg and text colours based on variables stored in an array, and I'm really struggling!

I have tried using a few methods, but I am very new to Swift and don't understand all of the logic behind what is and isn't best practice here.

This is my array:

`let testItem = [["Name Here"], ["red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1"], ["red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1"]]`

And basically I thought I would be able to do something like this:

```
labelOne.backgroundColor = UIColor(testItem[1])
labelOne.textColor = UIColor(testItem[2])
```

But of course, that won't work... so any ideas?

Comment: How do you store values in an array?

Comment: Your data structure is an array containing arrays with one element each.  Is that the intended format?  Something like this would be easier to work with:  `let testItem:[Any] = ["Name Here", UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)]`

Comment: You must be coming from web development where you can insert literal strings of code anywhere and have it function as that code. This is much different. When you put something in quotes, that thing is now of type `String` and can only be used as such.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can do this, and here are a few to help you understand data collections (there are other ways).

You can simply create an array of colors `[UIColor]`:

```
let colors = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.blue]

labelOne.backgroundColor = colors[0]
labelOne.textColor = colors[2]
```

You can store all of that one label's styling in a dictionary `[String : UIColor]`:

```
let labelOneStyling = ["background": UIColor.red, "text": UIColor.blue]

labelOne.backgroundColor = labelOneStyling["background"]
labelOne.textColor = labelOneStyling["text"]
```

You can store all label styling in a dictionary of dictionaries `[String : [String : UIColor]]`:

```
let allLabelStyling = ["labelOne": ["background": UIColor.red, "text": UIColor.blue], "labelTwo": ["background": UIColor.green, "text": UIColor.yellow]]

labelOne.backgroundColor = allLabelStyling["labelOne"]?["background"]
labelOne.textColor = allLabelStyling["labelOne"]?["text"]
```

A really useful tip is to option-click on any property, like the `colors` array in the first example, and select "Show Quick Help". Xcode will tell you what type that property is. You will see `let colors: [UIColor]` which tells you that colors is a constant of type array of UIColors. Swift is a strongly-typed language and types are the building blocks of OOP so if there is anything to learn right off the bat, types are it.